# C#: Richtextbox change my background color when i minimize my form

Tags: c#

I make an application to filter the traffic on a bussystem. This application is written with Visual Studio in C# and Winform. I read the traffic on the bus with help from an arduino, in front of ever byte I receive i set a flag e.g. _1, _2 or _3. I receive the data on a backgroundworker at the pc, than I push them all data in a string. With help from that string i can analyze the data and display it in a richtextbox. That all works fine but when i minimize the richtextbox while my programm running, my richtextbox mixed the background color. To set the background color i send a second flag from the Arduino to the PC e.g. _21 = grey and _20 = white.

On the following picture you can see it. All looks good, than i minimize it and the color mixed and when i maximize the form all is good again.

[image]

Here the code for the coloring:

```
 TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.SelectionStart + TextBox.SelectionLength;
 if (TextBox.SelectionStart == 0)
 TextBox.SelectionLength = dataArray[i].Length;

 else
 TextBox.SelectionLength = dataArray[i].Length + 1;

 if (colorArray[i] == "1")
 TextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGray;

 else if (colorArray[i] == "0") 
 TextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

 else
 TextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
```

I have absolutely no idea what must I surch in google to fix it. When someone need more information pls write it as comment and i will add it or when someone know which tag this problem can be edit. I´m absolutely helpless.

I hope someone know what I must do with friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: Is it just the colors that are incorrect? Or is the data also in the wrong place? And I presume you mean making the form smaller, minimizing would hide it on the task bar.

Comment: It´s just the color the data are correct i stream them in a file and at this file all is fine and i mean to hide it on the taskbar.

Comment: if you are minimizing the form, then how are you able to see the color change?

Comment: I see it when i scroll up the picture show it